# Read csv file in R with double quotes

Tags: r, csv

Suppose I have a csv file looks like this:

```
Type,ID,NAME,CONTENT,RESPONSE,GRADE,SOURCE
A,3,"","I have comma, ha!",I have open double quotes",A,""
```

desired output should be:

```
df <- data.frame(Type='A',ID=3, NAME=NA, CONTENT='I have comma, ha!',
                 RESPONSE='I have open double quotes\"', GRADE=A, SOURCE=NA)
df
  Type ID NAME           CONTENT                   RESPONSE GRADE SOURCE
1    A  3   NA I have comma, ha! I have open double quotes"     A     NA
```

I tried to use `read.csv`, since the data provider uses quote to escape comma in the string, but they forgot to escape double quotes in string with no comma, so no matter whether I disable quote in `read.csv` I won't get desired output.

How can I do this in R? Other package solutions are also welcome.

Comment: ``read.csv("data.csv", quote='', sep=',')`` doesn't work because the ``content`` column will be wrong. ``read.csv("data.csv", quote='')`` doesn't work because the columns are not separated properly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fread` from `data.table` handles this just fine:

```
library(data.table)

fread('Type,ID,NAME,CONTENT,RESPONSE,GRADE,SOURCE
A,3,"","I have comma, ha!",I have open double quotes",A,""')
#   Type ID NAME           CONTENT                   RESPONSE GRADE SOURCE
#1:    A  3      I have comma, ha! I have open double quotes"     A
```

Comment: Nice one. Should have thought of that myself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure about the structure of CSV files, but you said the author had escaped the comma in the text under content.

This works to read the text as is with the `"` at the end.

```
read.csv2("Test.csv", header = T,sep = ",", quote="")
```

Comment: How is this different from just `read.csv(text = text, quote="")`? Though this also doesn't give the desired output I guess.

Comment: Tried this solution. Columns get shifted so it won't get desired output.

Comment: Actually with this solution the column are also being split.

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid CSV, so you'll have to do your own parsing. But, assuming the convention is as follows, you can just toggle with `scan` to take advantage of most of its abilities:

1. If the field starts with a quote, it is quoted.
2. If the field does not start with a quote, it is raw

```
next_field<-function(stream) {
  p<-seek(stream)
  d<-readChar(stream,1)
  seek(stream,p)
  if(d=="\"")    
    field<-scan(stream,"",1,sep=",",quote="\"",blank=FALSE)   
  else
    field<-scan(stream,"",1,sep=",",quote="",blank=FALSE)
  return(field)
}
```

Assuming the above convention, this sufficient to parse as follows

```
s<-file("example.csv",open="rt")
header<-readLines(s,1)
header<-scan(what="",text=header,sep=",")
line<-replicate(length(header),next_field(s))

setNames(as.data.frame(lapply(line,type.convert)),header)
```

```
  Type ID NAME           CONTENT                   RESPONSE GRADE SOURCE
1    A  3   NA I have comma, ha! I have open double quotes"     A     NA
```

However, in practice you might want to first write back the fields, quoting each, to another file, so you can just `read.csv` on the corrected format.